# My mqsql_query function doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I just started with PHP.
I am currently working on a login script for my webpage.
When I try to run `mysql_query(SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$username)`
it doesn't work.
I made sure I used the right names,
but I have always had a problem with the query function.
This is my code, does anyone see the problem?

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{
    $connect = mysql_connect("host", "dbname", "password!") or die ("Couldnt connect!");
    mysql_select_db("TwoogLogin") or die ('couldnt find datebase');

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$username") or die ('unable to run query');

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    echo $numrows;
}
else
    die("Please enter a username and a password");
?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: You should not post passwords in here...

Comment: Your `$username` variable is neither escaped nor quoted in the query. Ask `mysql_error()` for details. Better yet, while unversed, read up a contemporary tutorial on [PDO and bound parameters](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: try to use print_r($numrows) instead echo for array

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/content/58/10132358/html/twoog/login/login.php on line 14

but this is the mysql_num_rows($query]; whitch gets this error

Comment: Never use "SELECT * ", use "SELECT username, password, ... " instead. "SELECT * " queries the entire database looking just to fetch those two or more specified columns ... Also, your query is wide open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username!=='' && $password!==''){
$connect = mysql_connect("host", "dbname", "password!");
if (!$connect)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("TwoogLogin",$connect);
if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Cannot use TwoogLogin: " . mysql_error());
  }

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$numrows = mysql_query($query,$connect);
echo mysql_num_rows($numrows);

mysql_close($connect);
}else{
echo "Please enter a username and a password";
}
?>
```

As suggested in the comment below (@Pascamel) `msql_*` extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


if ($username!=='' && $password!==''){
$connect = mysqli_connect("host", "dbname", "password!");
if (!$connect)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db("TwoogLogin",$connect);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$numrows = mysqli_query($query,$connect);
echo mysqli_num_rows($numrows);

mysqli_close($connect);
}else{
echo "Please enter a username and a password";
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5, you should give a solution with mysqli_* functions instead. Just sayin'

Comment: @Pascamel you're right I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Set appropriate value for the following statements
$connect = mysql_connect("mysql_server", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or die ("Couldnt connect!");
mysql_select_db("database_name",$connect) or die ('couldnt find datebase');


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username && $password)
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'") or die ('unable to run query');

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    echo $numrows;
}
else
    die("Please enter a username and a password");
?>
```

Comment: I have the appropriate values for my connection to the db, and i have connected successfully, u just have problem selecting data from the db, and running a query on the table...

Answer (score -1):

Bad syntax in your query! you should use username='$username'
another reason is about bad name of column are you sure the name of your columns are right??

Comment: I am sure that my colums are right yes, i still get the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/content/58/10132358/html/twoog/login/login.php on line 13

Comment: Ok check the $query content I think it's false so when you pass it to mysql_num_rows it can not count because $query is null!! so there is something wrong in your Query please check your variables. use this isset($username) to check that it's not an empty or null varaiable

Comment: I didnt get what you wanted me to do, may u try explain in a diffrent way? (pretty sure that my user is defined in the rifht way)

Comment: use the php function that name is isset() to sure that your post variables are not empty, ok?